# Expand a C array inside a function

Tags: c, pointers

This works in a main, but breaks when put into a function. I'm not sure how to reassign the pointer after passing into a function.

```
void expandArray(int** arr[], int* size) {
    int *temp;
    *temp = *arr;

    *arr = (int*) malloc(*size * 2 * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        printf("assigning from temp: %d ", temp[i]);
        arr[i] = temp[i];
        printf("to arr: %d \n", arr[i]);
    }

    *size = *size * 2;
    free(temp);
}

main(){
    int *arr;
    arr = (int*) malloc(maxSize * sizeof(int));
    if ....
        expandArray(arr, &arrSize);
    // use bigger arr for other stuff
}
```

Comment: how is arr declared in main?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `main`, `arr` is declared as `int *arr`. When `main` calls `expandArray`, it should pass a pointer to `arr`, which is written `&arr` and has type `int **a`.

However, you declared the parameter to `expandArray` as `int **arr[]`, adding additional brackets. Those are unnecessary and change the type, and your compiler should have warned you about that. Pay attention to compiler warnings. Be sure you understand them, and resolve them before proceeding.

In `expandArray`, you use both `arr[i]` and `temp[i]` to access the array. However, `arr[i]` is not a correct way to access array elements. When the declaration of the `arr` parameter is corrected, it will be `int **arr`, and it will not be proper to refer to an element of the array as `arr[i]`. It will be `(*arr)[i]`.

Commonly, to make this a little less confusion, authors will use a temporary variable to hold the pointer, so they do not need the extra asterisk:

```
int *NewArray = malloc(...); // Get new space.
*arr = NewArray;             // Send new address to caller.
...
   NewArray[i] = temp[i];    // Use temporary variable for access.
```

Some other points:

- When calling `malloc`, use `sizeof *p`, where `p` is the pointer being assigned to, rather than `sizeof(int)`. This is better because, if you later want to change the type for `p`, it only has to be changed in its declaration, not also in the `sizeof`. Then there is less likely to be a mistake where it is changed in one place and not another.
- Do not cast the result of `malloc`. This is unnecessary in C, although it is required in C++.
- `main` should be declared as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, not as `main()`. (C implementations may also provide for other forms.)
- Use `size_t` for sizes of arrays, not `int`, and either `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` for indices of arrays.

Overall, the code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void expandArray(int **arr, int *size)
{
    //  Record old pointer and size in temporary variables for convenience.
    int   *OldArray = arr;
    size_t OldSize  = *size;

    //  Prepare new size and pointer.
    size_t NewSize  = 2 * OldSize;
    int   *NewArray = malloc(NewSize * sizeof *NewArray);

    //  Handle allocation failure.
    if (!NewArray)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //  Copy data from old array to new array.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < OldSize; ++i)
        NewArray[i] = OldArray[i];

    //  Send new size and pointer to caller.
    *size = NewSize;
    *arr  = NewArray;

    //  Release old memory.
    free(OldArray);
}


int main(void)
{
    int *arr;
    arr = malloc(InitialSize * sizeof *arr);
    if (...)
        expandArray(&arr, &arrSize);
    // use bigger arr for other stuff
}
```

Comment: when the OP calls expandArray, he should pass a pointer to arr as the first parameter: `expandArray(&arr, *arrSize);`.

Comment: @bruceg It should be `expandArray(&arr, &arrSize);` - with ampersands at both arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I think the arr sould be int ** type.

```
void expandArray(int** arr, int* size) {
    int *temp;
    temp = *arr;

    *arr = (int*) malloc(*size * 2 * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        printf("assigning from temp: %d ", temp[i]);
        (*arr)[i] = temp[i];
        printf("to arr: %d \n", (*arr)[i]);
    }

    *size = *size * 2;
    free(temp);
}
```

If you just want to expand the array size, you can use realloc.
And the extended area should be initialized using memset.

```
void expandArray(int** arr, int* size) {
    *arr = (int*) realloc(*arr, *size * 2 * sizeof(int));
    memset(*arr+*size, 0, *size * sizeof(int));
    *size = *size * 2;
}
```